# Parsing e-mail only with imap in python

Tags: python, regex, imap

```
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
conn.login("login", "pass")
conn.select()
typ, data = conn.search(None, 'ALL')
z = open("email.txt", "a")

for num in data[0].split():
    typ, msg_data = conn.fetch(num, '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM)])')
    for response_part in msg_data:
        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
            msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
            subject = msg['from']
            z.write("%s\n" % subject) 
            print(subject)

    typ, response = conn.store(num, '+FLAGS', r'(\Seen)')
finally:
try:
    conn.close()
except:
    pass
conn.logout()
```

I want the FROM: section from header only. Not full name also. I am now getting data returned as "First name  LAst NAME" email@email.com the way I want the data is email@email.com

Comment: What do you want the list to contain? The body of the email, or the header of the email?

Comment: The list should contain the email address only. Without first/last name

Comment: Which email address? The From, To, CC, BCC, etc. You have to be specific. What if there are multiple addresses? Which address do you want? All of them, the first one, a _specific_ one?

Comment: I want the first one only from the From section as indicated by the code.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `envelope` data item, not `body.peek[header.fields (...)]`. When you ask for `envelope`, the server does mucho parsing and gives you From, Subject and a few more. In the case of From you get a list of tuples, each of which may look like this: ("Google Play" NIL "googleplay-noreply" "google.com"). The first is the name you don't care about, the second is of historical interest only, and the third and fourth are what you want.